# How can I output multiple lines of a text file in HTML using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, text-files, readfile

This is only the section of the code that I can't solve. The idea is that I open the text file, which I can do, and then I output each line in the div with the id cont. when I open the text file nothing gets output. I don't know why.

```
<head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
</head>
  
<body>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br>
    <div id ="cont"></div>
      
    <script>
        document.getElementById('file').onchange = function()
        {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(progressEvent)
            {    
                var fileContentArray = this.result.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                for(var line = 0; line < lines.length-1; line++)
                {
                    document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = lines[line];
                }
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }
    </script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: OP isn't adding new elements to the page with the same ID @dippas, just accessing the same element. So it should probably be `document.getElementById("cont").innerText += lines[line]; + '\n'` to concatenate new lines to the text content.

Comment: `reader.onload = function(progressEvent) { 
 document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = this.result.replace(/(\r?\n)/, "<br/>"); }`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.